# WooCommerce how to receive WebHooks data?

Tags: woocommerce, webhooks

I'm new in WooCommerce WebHooks development.

- I enable woocommerce rest api
- Create webhook action on Order Create.
- Setup action url.

I also tried to save webhooks triggered value into a file.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$action = json_decode($json, true);

$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $action;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);

fclose($myfile);
```

But I doesn't triggeged to my code.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it:

```
<?php
$webhookContent = "";



$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

$webhook = fopen('php://input' , 'rb');
    while (!feof($webhook)) {
        $webhookContent .= fread($webhook, 4096);
    }


$txt = $webhookContent;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);

fclose($myfile);

?>
```